# PDO Script Not Working Possible Database or Script Error

Tags: php, pdo

I made a script that pulls news posts from my database using PDO, however it is not working properly. Can anyone check my files to see what I am doing wrong, and possibly suggest a fix, and explain why it is not working so I can learn from my mistakes. Also if you would let me know if my code is prone to injection or other vulnerabilities, I would appreciate it.

Script:

```
<?php
require_once("config/config.php");

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
foreach($dbh->query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $body = $row ['body'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    echo "<center><b>$title posted on $date</center></b><hr>";
    echo nl2br($body);
    echo "<hr>";
}
$dbh = null;
?>
```

config.php:

```
<?php 
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_NAME", "ninjaz_gaming");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "Newman13");
?>
```

Comment: And what's the issue?

Comment: You don't seem to be using OOP, so why `$this->db_connection`? And its not being used subsequently either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primary problem is that you are not storing the PDO connection handle in a variable which you use down the road.

There is no `$this` in your code which I can see, no classes no objects hence here

```
$this->db_connection = new PDO(...);
^^^^ this what?
```

It should be

```
$dbh = new PDO(...);
```

Other than that there are no obvious errors. You should also turn on error reporting while production.

You can also simplify your code like this

```
$dbh = new PDO(...);
foreach($dbh->query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC",PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row){
    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $body = $row ['body'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    echo "<center><b>$title posted on $date</center></b><hr>";
    echo nl2br($body);
    echo "<hr>";
}
```

Since you do not use any user provided input in your query it has no issues as far as sql injection is concerned, but sooner or later you will have to use user provided values in queries and hence you can take 1 step further now and use prepared statements. Since you're using PDO already it wont be much of a problem.

Comment: Then you should turn on error reporting to see where the actual error is

Answer (score 0):

connection.php

```
    <?php
define("DB_HOST", "localhost");
define("DB_NAME", "ninjaz_gaming");
define("DB_USER", "root");
define("DB_PASS", "Newman13");

function connectDb(){
    try {
        $db_connection = new PDO('mysql:host='. DB_HOST .';dbname='. DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        return $db_connection;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Sorry, there was a problem connecting to the database." . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

Script

```
<?php
        include('connection.php');

        $dbh = connectDb();
        $query = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY id DESC");
        $query->execute();


        while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $title = $row['title'];
            $body = $row ['body'];
            $date = $row['date'];

            echo "<center><b>$title posted on $date</center></b><hr>";
            echo nl2br($body);
            echo "<hr>";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't realise there was no fetching in the script ^^ I edited it, please try now.